# SOQL: Execute Anonymous and Query Editor returning different results

Tags: apex, soql, execute-anonymous, query-editor

I'm trying to query Task from Lead. In the developer console > query editor, I have the following SOQL query:

```
 SELECT name, (SELECT id, subject, description FROM Tasks)
 FROM Lead
 WHERE id = '00JQ0000005h0FfQPP'
 LIMIT 1
```

This returns

> Name: Robby
>
> Robson Tasks:
>   [{"Id":"00JT000000YzDA9NNP","Subject":"Call","Description":"Had a call
>   with Robbie. Need to follow up in a week."}]

But when I execute the following in the anonymous window:

```
lead d = [SELECT name, (SELECT id, subject, description FROM Tasks)
          FROM Lead
          WHERE id = '00JQ0000005h0FfQPP'
          LIMIT 1];
system.debug(d);
```

I just get:

> |USER_DEBUG|[10]|DEBUG|Lead:{Name=Robby Robson, Id=00JQ0000005h0FfQPP}

The purpose of the script is to fetch the description from the latest task associated with the lead. Originally I thought I could just do this:

```
string lastNote = [SELECT (SELECT description FROM Tasks Order By CreatedDate Limit 1)
                   FROM Lead
                   WHERE id = :upsertedLeads[i].getId()
                   LIMIT 1].tasks[0].description;
```

But that returns an index out of bounds, due to tasks[0].

How should I proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.debug(d) is the issue because d has been defined as a lead record. If you want the task, than debug that. It's not that your query isn't working, you just aren't debugging more than the lead record.

But, I agree that you should just query task directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly query the Task object using the Lead Id and use the description without doing the parent child subquery.

```
Task recentLeadTask = [Select Id, Description From Task Where WhoId = :YourLeadId Order By CreatedDate Limit 1];  
if(recentLeadTask != null)  
    String taskDescription = recentLeadTask.Description;
```

looking at your last part of code, it seems you are running this query inside a loop which is not generally not recommended since it will hit the governor limits..

if that's the case consider moving the query out of the loop.

Comment: Good call regarding the loop. It's a bad habit of mine. Your method totally works - but why isn't mine working as well?